# AxInterop doesn't generate

Tags: c#, com, interop, ocx

back in VS2017, when referencing an OCX two files were created and referenced:

- Interop.XYZLib.dll
- AxInterop.XYZLib.dll

from there I was able to create a wrapper around AxInterop.XYZLib.dll that exposes the methods and properties of the OCX as if they are native. Now after installing VS2019 only Interop.XYZLib.dll is generated. Even if I go back to VS2017 the behavior is the same, only one is generated, and trying to use it causes a catastrophic failure. Other answers suggest to use AxImp.exe, I did only to have a error saying that "Did not find a registered ActiveX control in ...", that's not true the OCX is registered with RegSvr32.exe, any ideas?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Ax dll are still created with Visual Studio 2019 but not with any type of C# project. For example, it works with a Winforms .NET Framework project, not for a console app project.

Comment: Seriously? whoa, I noticed that, if I drop the OCX on a Winform in VS2019 it works, it creates both files. It baffles me that it used to work on 2017 for C#, but after installing 2019 it stopped working, whoa, disappointing. Thank you Simon!!

Comment: Check the ComReference in your project file and make sure WrapperTool is set to aximp instead of Tlbimp. It looks like this was changed in latest VS 2019.

Comment: Hi @NullReference, thank you and yes, that's what I'm doing on the working version on 2017, but I can't have Visual Studio to create the AxImp properly on new code.

Comment: edit the project file and as i advised set wrapper tool to aximp , have you done that ?

Comment: Hi @NullReference, I can't since the Aximp file is not created when referencing the OCX, and when manually generated with AxImp Visual Studio doesn't like it. I opened a ticket with Microsoft and they said it is a  "regression", they asked for code, I sent the code, still waiting on them, when I hear back I'll post here, thank you